SQL Server applying ORDER BY .. OFFSET only to UNION subquery
In SQL Server 2022 (and earlier), this behaves as I'd expect, according to the SQL standard:
select i
from (values (1)) as t (i)
union 
select i
from (values (2), (3)) as t (i)
order by i
offset 0 rows
fetch next 1 rows only

It produces:
|i  |
|---|
|1  |

So, like everywhere else, the ORDER BY .. OFFSET clause is applied to the result of the unions. However, when I nest the above query in a derived table or CTE, then the semantics seems to change (assume the actual query is much more complex):
select *
from (
  select i
  from (values (1)) as t (i)
  union 
  select i
  from (values (2), (3)) as t (i)
  order by i
  offset 0 rows
  fetch next 1 rows only
) t;

This produces:
|i  |
|---|
|1  |
|2  |

Now, the ORDER BY .. OFFSET clause is applied to the UNION's second subquery only. Is this specified behaviour? I cannot seem to find authoritative information in the ORDER BY docs, which read:

In a query that uses UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT operators, ORDER BY is allowed only at the end of the statement. This restriction applies only to when you specify UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT in a top-level query and not in a subquery. See the Examples section that follows.

But there's no example showing this particular case. The SELECT docs's syntax diagrams don't really support ORDER BY in UNION subqueries, only in top-level <SELECT statement>, so that documentation seems outdated / incomplete as well.
Is this a well known bug?

I did! The fetch must allow it.

I'm 99% sure this is a SQL Server bug. The query runs perfectly well in Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, and MySQL.

@TheImpaler: It was my first reaction as well, when I asked the question. But do check out my answer where I'm showing an example that hints at this being by design / intentional. ORDER BY .. OFFSET seems to be local to the UNION subquery, not global to the UNION output, when the UNION is executed in a subquery. This doesn't look like an accident / bug.

@LukasEder Will need to review the SQL Standard again (zzz), but as far as I remember the ORDER BY/LIMIT/OFFSET apply to the "combined query" (that is, the result of the set operators) and not the last SELECT in the combined query. Once I get the chance I'll review it.

@TheImpaler: That's how the SQL standard defines it, yes, and so does SQL Server, for top level queries. But SQL Server (historically Sybase T-SQL) may have had a different idea on how the syntax should work, depending on context. T-SQL isn't generally the most compliant dialect. Again, the simple fact that in a subquery, all UNION subqueries (including the non-last ones) are allowed to have ORDER BY .. OFFSET clauses hints at there being intention in this language design, which just looks weird if only the last UNION subquery has the clause, not otherwise.

Bug or not
It's unlikely a bug, just an interesting design choice of how SELECT works as a top level query (similar to standard SQL) vs how it works as a subquery. This example shows that all UNION subqueries can have "local" ORDER BY .. OFFSET clauses, and the trailing clause isn't a global one over the UNION output:
select *
from (
  select i
  from (values (1), (2)) as t (i)
  order by i
  offset 0 rows
  fetch next 1 rows only
  union 
  select i
  from (values (3), (4)) as t (i)
  order by i
  offset 0 rows
  fetch next 1 rows only
) t;

This produces:
|i  |
|---|
|1  |
|3  |

So, this hints at there simply being missing / inconsistent documentation.
If the subquery is run as a top-level query, then this error is raised:

SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

Workaround
Just nest the set operation once more in a derived table:
select *
from (
  select *
  from (
    select i
    from (values (1)) as t (i)
    union 
    select i
    from (values (2), (3)) as t (i)
  ) t
  order by i
  offset 0 rows
  fetch next 1 rows only
) t;

Now, the ORDER BY .. OFFSET clause behaves again, and applies to the complete UNION output, producing the expected result:
|i  |
|---|
|1  |


see: DBFIDDLE which I created, but I was too late for the answer

@Luuk: Thanks for trying. I already knew this workaround and documented it here for future me, who will stumble upon this question again for sure, according to the recommendations: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Stackoverflow is saying the same: Can I answer my own question?

The docs are on Github so at least you can raise an issue and pull on them

@Charlieface: I did provide feedback. I won't send a PR, because this seems way more strategic than just a simple typo.

No, this is a SQL Server bug; the result doesn't make sense at all. The query runs perfectly well in Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, and MySQL.

@TheImpaler: Dialects are allowed to implement different semantics for different language features. Otherwise, Oracle's 'a' || NULL = 'a' behaviour would also be a bug, yet it's just a different implementation. I could give you hundreds of similar examples.
